# SymPy unable to simplify solution

Tags: sympy, convex-optimization

I am trying to solve the following system of equation using sympy.

```
from sympy import *

n = 4
K = 2

a = symbols(f"a_:{int(n)}", real=True)
b = symbols(f"b_:{int(n)}", real=True)
X = symbols(f"X_:{int(K)}", real=True)
Y = symbols(f"Y_:{int(K)}", real=True)

lambda_ = symbols("lambda",real=True)
mu = symbols(f"mu_:{int(K)}", real=True)

list_eq = [
    # (1)
    Eq(a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[3], 0),
    Eq(a[0] + a[1], X[0]),
    Eq(a[2] + a[3], X[1]),
    # (2)

    Eq(b[0] + b[1] + b[2] + b[3], 0),
    Eq(b[0] + b[1], Y[0]),
    Eq(b[2] + b[3], Y[1]),

    # (3)
    Eq(b[0], a[0] - lambda_ - mu[0]),
    Eq(b[1], a[1] - lambda_ - mu[0]),
    Eq(b[2], a[2] - lambda_ - mu[1]),
    Eq(b[3], a[3] - lambda_ - mu[1]),
]

solve(list_eq, dict=True)

[{X_0: -b_2 - b_3 + mu_0 - mu_1,
  X_1: b_2 + b_3 - mu_0 + mu_1,
  Y_0: -b_2 - b_3,
  Y_1: b_2 + b_3,
  a_0: -b_1 - b_2 - b_3 + mu_0/2 - mu_1/2,
  a_1: b_1 + mu_0/2 - mu_1/2,
  a_2: b_2 - mu_0/2 + mu_1/2,
  a_3: b_3 - mu_0/2 + mu_1/2,
  b_0: -b_1 - b_2 - b_3,
  lambda: -mu_0/2 - mu_1/2}]
```

The analytical solution for b is

```
b_0 = a_0 + (1/2)*(Y_0 - X_0)
b_1 = a_1 + (1/2)*(Y_0 - X_0)
b_2 = a_2 + (1/2)*(Y_1 - X_1)
b_3 = a_3 + (1/2)*(Y_1 - X_1)
```

However sympy does not manage to simplify the results and is still using mu_0 and mu_1 in the solution.
Is it possible to simplify those variables in the solution ?

For more details, the system i'm trying to solve is an optimization problem under constraints:
`min_b || a - b ||^2` such that `b_0 + b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 0` and `b_0 + b_1 = Y_0` and `b_2 + b_3 = Y_1`.
We assume that `a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 0` and `a_0 + a_1 = X_0` and `a_2 + a_3 = X_1`.
Therefore, the equations (1) are the assumptions on a and the equations (2) and (3) are the KKT equations.

Comment: You haven't told solve which symbols to solve for and there are 10 equations but 14 symbols. I expect that if your problem is well posed then you can get answer you want by passing the appropriate list of unknowns but from your description it isn't clear to me what that list should be.

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate variables from a system of linear or polynomial equations using a Groebner basis:

```
In [61]: G = groebner(list_eq, [*mu, lambda_, *b, *a, *X, *Y])

In [62]: for eq in G: pprint(eq)
X₁ - Y₁ + 2⋅λ + 2⋅μ₀
-X₁ + Y₁ + 2⋅λ + 2⋅μ₁
X₁ + Y₁ + 2⋅a₁ + 2⋅b₀
-X₁ + Y₁ - 2⋅a₁ + 2⋅b₁
-X₁ - Y₁ + 2⋅a₃ + 2⋅b₂
X₁ - Y₁ - 2⋅a₃ + 2⋅b₃
X₁ + a₀ + a₁
-X₁ + a₂ + a₃
X₀ + X₁
Y₀ + Y₁
```

Here the first two equations have `mu` and `lambda` but the others have these symbols eliminated. You can use `G[2:]` to get the equations that do not involve `mu` and `lambda`. The order of the symbols in a lex Groebner basis determines which symbols are eliminated first from the equations. You can solve specifically for `b` in terms of `a`, `X` and `Y` by picking out the equations involving `b`:

```
In [63]: solve(G[2:6], b)
Out[63]: 
⎧      X₁   Y₁           X₁   Y₁           X₁   Y₁             X₁   Y₁     ⎫
⎨b₀: - ── - ── - a₁, b₁: ── - ── + a₁, b₂: ── + ── - a₃, b₃: - ── + ── + a₃⎬
⎩      2    2            2    2            2    2              2    2      ⎭
```

This is not exactly the form you suggested but the form of solution for the problem is not unique because of the constraints among the variables it is expressed in. There are many equivalent ways to express `b` in terms of `a`, `X` and `Y` even after eliminating `mu` and `lambda` because `a`, `X` and `Y` are not independent (they are 8 symbols connected by 4 constraints).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes adding auxiliary equations with the pattern you desire and indicating what you don't want as a solution variable can help you get closer to what you desired:

```py
[38] eqs = list_eq + [Y[0]-X[0]-var('z0'), Y[1]-X[1]-var('z1')]
[39] sol = Dict(solve(eqs, exclude=a, dict=True)[0]); sol
```

[image]